# Google keeps rejecting update citing vulnerability in current production release (old build)

Tags: android, google-play

We are currently at the end of our rope here with Google and their complete lack of support. Hoping someone here might have experienced this issue before and give any hint as to what the issue is. Right now Google keeps rejecting our new builds (which fixes the vulnerability in our current production app). In the rejection emails they keep referencing the same older build we have in production with the vulnerability. I am not sure how we can fix this if they keep rejecting us based on our production build. The screenshot below is the email we get no matter how many times we push a new build. We have tried everything we can think of over the past 2 weeks. It always references our production build of 564 even though we are on build 600 now.

[image]

To the note that we might not have resolved the issue, we have a separate staging app that is used for internal testing. This app was also rejected for the same reason but after fixing the vulnerability is now being accepted. If I undo the fix we are rejected again. This leads me to believe we have fixed the issue. To the note that maybe we didn't wait long enough, this has been going on for two weeks now as we have tried contacting Google on every support link they have only to either be ignored or told they can not help with policy rejection reasons.

Comment: we are having the same issue now, did you manage to get that resolved?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After weeks of literally no help we finally figured it out. Here is what someone higher up at google suggested that resolved our issue:

> I understand that you have a new submission with App Bundle 2, however for further review please DEACTIVATE the non-compliant version (App Bundle 1, Production) before submitting an update to prevent any further rejection.

Apparently when you submit an update Google reviews all active versions which will include your current production version. They will then reject you update if they find an issue with your active production app. Deactivating our production app did not take it off the Play Store but just made it so that it was not available after we pushed the update.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am facing the same issue since few days. you save me. thank you. :)

Comment: Hi there, how did you 'DEACTIVATE' the non-compliant app? I see no option in Bundle explorer to actually do this, and I've also ensured the problematic APK is listed under 'Not included' when making a new release. At the same level of exasperation you were.

Comment: Late but might help other, you have to do a 100% rollout with deactivating your current production build

Comment: @Osman previous rejected version of production also shows in review when i upload incremented build in internal testing.  I don't how to solve this. plz help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F68KF.png

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem.
google play inform us by mail about policy violation
so we solve the error and create new apk
But when we uploaded apk in beta track review it kept rejecting them and send the same production version number error mail again and again.
Until I came to know that whenever we upload a new apk they again check production as well and kept sending reject mail
So I need to deactivate all beta track and production apk
and upload new APK in production
and It took almost 2 days to get the approval of the newly uploaded apk